# Cache file mapped by url in the browser

Tags: http, caching, servlets, spring-mvc, cache-control

I have a method mapped in a url like /foo/*/image which downloads an image, and I want the browser to cache that picture. But I'm not getting it. I can see in Firefox with firebug that the request is not being cached, and it also happens in Chrome.

I'm trying to set Cache-Control to "max-age=3600, public" in the method, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Below is a piece of code of the method called in the controller made by Spring-MVC.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo/{id}/image", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void showImage(
            @PathVariable("id") String id,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Model model) throws Exception{

        //add image to the response
        service.read(id, response);

        //mark the response as cacheable
        HttpServletResponse httpResp = ((HttpServletResponse) response);
        httpResp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=3600, public");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`<mvc:resources>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources). There you can set up caching.

Apart from that, make sure your request doesn't go through a proxy that overrides headers, and make sure the response isn't redirected.

Comment: the image which is downloaded is not stored in a folder, it's stored in a datastore so I think I can't use mvc:resources

Comment: @ Bozho **this is off topic (but from JAVA):** Can you please explain me the difference between `setPreferredSize()` and `setSize()` and what does `pack()` do ?

Comment: @Bozho I don't have a proxy (it's in a localhost appengine server) and the image is served using the blobstore api of GAE inside the  service.read method. And I don't redirect the response AFAIK.

Comment: so you set the header, but you aren't getting in in the browser?